# Sequelize geospatial query: find "n" closest points to a location

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sequelize.js, geospatial, postgis

Using [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) and geospatial queries, if I want to find the "n" closest points to a certain location, how should the Sequelize query be?

Assume I have a model that looks something like this:

```
sequelize.define('Point', {geo: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT')});
```

Now let's say we input 100 random points in the db through something like:

```
db.Point.create({geo: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [randomLng,randomLat]}});
```

Imagine we have a `lat` and `lng` variables to define a location, and we want to find the 10 closest points to it. when I run this query I get an error:

```
const location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${lat} ${lng})', 4326)`);

db.Point.findAll({
  attributes: [['distance', sequelize.fn('ST_Distance', sequelize.col('Point'), location)]],
  order: 'distance',
  limit: 10
});

// -> TypeError: s.replace is not a function
```

Any idea what is the issue / how to fix it?

Thx!

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you have extra square brackets around attributes

Comment: any news on this one?

Answer (score 11):

MySQL can give an error that function `ST_Distance_Sphere` does not exist. In that case you can use this alternative solution:

I hold point information separately as latitude and longitude decimals. Assume you should have a model that looks something like this:

```
sequelize.define('Point', {latitude: DataTypes.DECIMAL(11,2)},
                          {longitude: DataTypes.DECIMAL(11,2)});
```

Imagine we have a `lat` and `lng` variables to define a location, and we want to find the 10 closest points to it:

```
db.Point.findAll({
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn('POW',sequelize.fn('ABS',sequelize.literal("latitude-"+lat)),2),'x1'],
               [sequelize.fn('POW',sequelize.fn('ABS',sequelize.literal("longitude-"+lng)),2),'x2']], 
  order: sequelize.fn('SQRT', sequelize.literal('x1+x2')),
  limit: 10
});
```

**Update:**

With [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), distance is more accurate:

```
db.Point.findAll({
  attributes: [[sequelize.literal("6371 * acos(cos(radians("+lat+")) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians("+lng+") - radians(longitude)) + sin(radians("+lat+")) * sin(radians(latitude)))"),'distance']],
  order: sequelize.col('distance'),
  limit: 10
});
```

Comment: How can I apply having or where on distance column ?

Comment: @AbhiBurk you can add where key inside the object in findAll 
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#applying-where-clauses

Comment: The Haversine formula part works very perfectly!

Answer (score 10):

When you surround **sequelize.fn** with brackets, you must also include a string as an alias:

```
[sequelize.fn('ST_Distance_Sphere', sequelize.literal('geolocation'), location), 'ALIASNAME']
```

Also, try changing `ST_Distance` to `ST_Distance_Sphere`. So:

```
    const location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${lng} ${lat})', 4326)`);

    User.findAll({
      attributes: [[sequelize.fn('ST_Distance_Sphere', sequelize.literal('geolocation'), location),'distance']],
      order: 'distance',
      limit: 10,
      logging: console.log
    })
    .then(function(instance){
      console.log(instance);
    })
```

This is actually working for me.
obs: be sure you substitute 'User' with the model in which you have the geometry data type.

**Update:** If you still can't order using `order: 'distance'`, maybe you should declare it in a var and use `order: distance` without quotes, like this:

```
    var lat = parseFloat(json.lat);
    var lng = parseFloat(json.lng);
    var attributes = Object.keys(User.attributes);

    var location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${lng} ${lat})')`);
    var distance = sequelize.fn('ST_Distance_Sphere', sequelize.literal('geolocation'), location);
    attributes.push([distance,'distance']);

    var query = {
      attributes: attributes,
      order: distance,
      include: {model: Address, as: 'address'},
      where: sequelize.where(distance, {$lte: maxDistance}),
      logging: console.log
    }
```

**Update on distance accuracy:**

The solution mentioned by **sarikaya** does seem to be more accurate. Here is how to do it using postgres:

```
var distance = sequelize.literal("6371 * acos(cos(radians("+lat+")) * cos(radians(ST_X(location))) * cos(radians("+lng+") - radians(ST_Y(location))) + sin(radians("+lat+")) * sin(radians(ST_X(location))))");
```

Comment: This query gives me the following error: `Error: Order must be type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method.` I tried to change `order` to `['distance']` instead of `'distance'` and now I get: `SequelizeDatabaseError: column User.distance does not exist`.

Comment: did you include the string 'distance' in the attributes?
distance without quotes should also work: ... `order: distance`...

Comment: I have added distance to attributes, but when I do where query it shows distance  Unknown column 'location' in 'field list'

Comment: Just going to mention that when using `POINT` longitude should be the first argument

Comment: what is `maxDistance` can you give a example of `maxDistance` please

Answer (score 6):

Building off **@Edudjr's** answer, this is what I did to get it to work in my project:

```
const location = sequelize.literal(`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${ startLongitude } ${  startLatitude })')`)
const distance = sequelize.fn('ST_Distance_Sphere', sequelize.col('location'), location)

const inRadius = await Position.findAll({
    order: distance,
    where: sequelize.where(distance, { $lte: radius }),
    logging: console.log
})
```

where Position is defined as:

```
sequelize.define('Position', {
    location: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT')
})
```

> Note that Point requires the coordinates in the format of (longitude
>   latitude)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209008/incorrect-arguments-to-st-distance-sphere-in-special-cases

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33410/whats-the-difference-between-pointx-y-and-geomfromtextpointx-y

Comment: what's the unit of radius ? kilometer or mile?