# Using Sequelize how can I get the closest n elements to a lat and long that lies within the radius of that object?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, geometry, sequelize.js, postgis

I have a model that looks like this:

```
sequelize.define('region', {
    origin: {
        type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
    },
    radius: {
        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
    }
}
```

I want to be able to find closest (to the origin) `regions` that contain a given `latitude` and `longitude`.

I saw from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012932/sequelize-geospatial-query-find-n-closest-points-to-a-location/46028055) question how to find the closest n `regions`. But I need to add something to the `where` that only returns `regions` where the distance between the given `lat` and `long` is less than or equal to `region.radius`.

```
var query = req.query;
var latitude = query.latitude;
var longitude = query.longitude;
var limit = query.limit || 10;

const myDistance = query.maxDistance || 10000; // **** If I can get this to be `region.radius` then I think it'll work
models.Region.findAll({
    attributes: {
    include: [
        [
        models.Sequelize.fn(
            'ST_Distance',
            models.Sequelize.col('origin'),
            models.Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', longitude, latitude)
        ),
        'distance'
        ]
    ]
    },
    where: models.Sequelize.where(
    models.Sequelize.fn(
        'ST_DWithin',
        models.Sequelize.col('origin'),
        models.Sequelize.fn('ST_MakePoint', longitude, latitude),
        myDistance
    ),
    true
    ), 
    order: models.Sequelize.literal('distance ASC')
}).then( regions => {
    return res.json(regions);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a raw SQL query with gis:

```
var query = req.query;
var latitude = parseFloat(query.latitude);
var longitude = parseFloat(query.longitude);
var limit = query.limit || 10;
const maxDistance = parseFloat(query.maxDistance) || 10000;

models.sequelize.query('SELECT "id", "origin", "radius", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "regionID", ST_Distance("origin", ST_MakePoint(?, ?), false) AS "distance" FROM "regions" AS "region" WHERE ST_DWithin("origin", ST_MakePoint(?, ?), ?, false) = true AND ST_Distance("origin", ST_MakePoint(?, ?), false) - radius <= 0 ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT ?;', { replacements: [latitude, longitude, latitude, longitude, maxDistance, latitude, longitude, limit], type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT, model: models.Region }).then( regions => {
    return res.json(regions);
});
```

Here is the better formatted (pseudo) SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM regions
WHERE ST_DWithin("origin", ST_MakePoint(lat, long), max, false) = true AND ST_Distance("origin", ST_MakePoint(lat, long), false) - radius <= 0 
ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 5;
```