# Functions in Sequelize and WHERE 1=1

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a problem. I am new to Sequelize, and running the following code

```
     const nearMeetis = await Meeti.findAll({
        where: Sequelize.where( Sequelize.fn( "ST_DistanceSphere",
        Sequelize.fn( "ST_MakePoint", parseFloat( -39.4193 ), parseFloat( -64.1795 ) ),
        Sequelize.col( "location" )), {
            [Op.lte]: 500
          }),
         logging: function(q){
            //console.log("q:", q);
         }
     })
```

The SQL generated by Sequelize is:

```
SELECT "idMeeti", "title", "slug", "speaker", "quantity", "description", "date", "hour", "address", "city", "state", "country", "location", "interested", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "userId", "groupId" FROM "meetis" AS "meeti" WHERE 1=1;
```

If I run the following SQL query in a SQL query editor and I get the correct results:

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(-39.4193, -64.1795), "location")  AS "distance", "idMeeti", "title"
FROM meetis
WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(-39.4193, -64.1795), "location") < 500
```

I am using:

PostgreSQL 12.3 and Sequelize 5.1.0

I hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE

The problem was resolved. The problem was that I was importing and using Sequelize as `const Sequelize = require('Sequelize')`, instead importing using sequelize from the db intance (`const sequelize = require('../../config/db')`).

Comment: R u using postgis?, It seems may PostGIS is not enabled on your postgres server.

Comment: @cybercoder, yes I am using PostGIS. When I run the SQL raw (In tableplus), it works, so, I think that the problem is in Sequelize. Thanks

Comment: See this question answers, May Alias is your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012932/sequelize-geospatial-query-find-n-closest-points-to-a-location

Comment: @cybercode, I also tried it but not works. The post is based in MySQL and not in PostgreSQL. Thanks.

Comment: This question along with the answer in the update deserves more recognition. I spent hours troubleshooting before finding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the `Sequelize.where` call like this:

```
  const nearMeetis = await Meeti.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.where( Sequelize.fn("ST_DistanceSphere",
    Sequelize.fn( "ST_MakePoint", parseFloat(-39.4193), parseFloat(-64.1795)),
    Sequelize.col("location")), Op.lte, 500),
     logging: function(q){
        //console.log("q:", q);
     }
 })
```

See [Sequelize.where in the documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-where)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. I tried your code but it still not works. The SQL Log, give me the same result WHERE 1=1.

Comment: I tried `where: database.Sequelize.where(database.Sequelize.fn("ST_DistanceSphere",
      database.Sequelize.fn("ST_MakePoint", parseFloat(-39.4193), parseFloat(-64.1795)),
      database.Sequelize.col("shape")), Op.lte, 500),` against my table with geometry column `shape` and it adds ` AND ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(-39.4193, -64.1795), "shape") <= 500)` to a `where` condition. Did you restart a server after changing the query?

Comment: Hi. I tried a reset even in Postgree, but it still not works. What version of **sequelize** and **PostgreSQL** are you using? How is defined the field in your model? Thanks!

Comment: Sequelize 4, PostgreSQL 9.6, field type is Geometry

Comment: `Sequelize.where` syntax is not changed from v4 to v5.

Comment: @Antony. Many thank for your response. I solved the problem as I describe before.